# Visual Studio Performance Profiler Missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The Performance Profiler or Diagnostic Tools are not showing up in Visual Studio for me, while it should be enabled by default. It seems to be totally missing. The 'Performance Profiler' option is not even available under the 'Debug' menu.

I have already tried pressing CTRL + ALT + F2 as mentioned in this post: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/missing-profiler-options-under-debug-visual-studio/441152

The option 'Enable Diagnostic Tools' is totally missing from 'Tools' -> 'Options' -> 'Debugging'.

I have updated my installation, so that should not be the issue. I run Visual Studio Community Edition. Is it possible it is not available under Community Edition?

Anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Get Tools and Features, then in the Visual Studio installer go to Individual Components, search for profiler and install whatever profiler you need: [image: Screenshot of installer]